# How to convert lazyload for canvases

Tags: javascript

i am new to the webdev and creating my own website for comics and there is a lot of thiefs lurking around, then i just started to search how to make their stealing hardest possible, and find a way which you turn the images into canvas, so that way people can not just go around and download images. but for the performance issues, the reading page is made lazyload, because sometimes an chapter can be 30 or 40+ mb. Right now i am having hard time to converting that system to canvas images, i hope i can find my answer.

My current code right below:

```
  <div class="icerik-bolum_sayfalar">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/0.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 0">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/1.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 1">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/2.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 2">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/3.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 3">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/4.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 4">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/5.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 5">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/6.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 6">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/7.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 7">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/8.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 8">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/9.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 9">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/10.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 10">
    <img class="icerik-bolum_sayfa" data-src="resim/bolum/11.jpg" alt="God of Blackfield - Bölüm 78 - Sayfa 11">
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
const page = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");

function srcToImg(img) {
  const src = img.dataset.src;
  if (!src) {
    return;
  }
  img.src = src;
}

const imgLoad = {
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "0px 0px 140px 0px",
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      srcToImg(entry.target);
      imgObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
}, imgLoad);

page.forEach((img) => imgObserver.observe(img));
```

For to be clear, if its possible what i want is there will be only canvas html tags and i will able to load them same princible as lazyload. Thank you for reading my problem, i hope its not too much for to ask.

Comment: Uh, regardless of what you do, the image urls are going to be accessible from the browsers network console in the developer tools.  Any web developer worth anything will know how to do that to grab your images.

Comment: @Taplar i know but it can block some plugins like the one has chrome (fatkun image downloader), so i am trying my best to what i can and find /:

Comment: <canvas> elements - if a user right-clicks on the canvas, many browsers will pop up a menu giving the user an opportunity to 'Save image As...' - which, I think, will defeat the effort you're putting in to convert images to canvases to prevent theft.